# QT QDesktopServices: how to view in childwindow?

Tags: c++, qt, pdf-viewer, qdesktopservices

I have QT Creator 5.2.1 .  I am using QDesktopServices to open a PDF file through Ubuntu's PDF viewer using the following line:

```
QDesktopServices::openUrl(QUrl("File Path", QUrl::TolerantMode));
```

The above line is written in my .cpp file. The PDF is opened in a separate window as expected. How would I open QDekstopServices inside a widget? the widget sits inside of my application.